# O jsoup и magnet-ссылках

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup, torrent

Программа на Java вытаскивает magnet ссылки со страницы определенного торрент-трекера.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader bR = null;
        StringBuilder sB = null;
        Proxy proxy = null;
        try {
            proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("185.13.228.124",8999));
            URL url = new URL("http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=817921");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(),"Windows-1251"));
            sB = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sB.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println();
        Document document = (Document) Jsoup.parse(sB.toString(), "Windows-1251");
        Elements links = document.select("a");

        System.out.println("Попробуем вывести");

        for (Element i:
             links) {
            if (i.attr("href").startsWith("magnet:?xt"))
            {
                System.out.println(i.attr("href"));
            }
        }
}
```

Просмотр исходного кода страницы показывает что значение магнета следующее:

```
<a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5C7CD6007C46B51D0CE157E8FF2294A7410CB340&amp;tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt.t-ru.org%2Fann%3Fmagnet&amp;dn=%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%2F%20Closer%20(%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81)%20%5B1080p%5D%20%5B2004%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%2C%20Blu-Ray%5D" class="magnet-link" data-topic_id="817921"> <img src="https://static.t-ru.org/templates/v1/images/icon_magnet_24_1.png" alt="">Скачать раздачу по magnet-ссылке</a>
```

Программа выводит:

[image: idea_terminal]

Внимание вопрос. Почему jsoup обрезает значение атрибута href?

Comment: Уверены что нужное значение есть там изначально, а не добавляется каким-то скриптом? Попробуйте вывести ссылку целиком, если значения нет - нужно пользоваться каким-то инструментом, что будет выполнять скрипты. Это может быть Selenium, либо даже WebView из JavaFx, а уже потом сохранять страницу как текст и парсить Jsoup

Answer (score 0):

Не понял зачем делать httpURLConnection если коннектиться можно с jsoup...
jsoup в данной ссылке правильно выводит ссылку это можно проверить посмотрев html код страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]